# Delete my own flags

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, flags

So I've done this once or twice now, where I've flagged a question, then looked at it again and gone..."OH...Whoops, Maybe I shouldn't of flagged that".

But once I've flagged something I can't remove my own flag.

Does anyone else think having a *"delete flag button"* would be useful?

Maybe in the flags section of my profile. If this already exists, could someone tell me how?

Comment: Forget about them. It happens and if they are indeed baseless, a mod will reject the flag.

Comment: @Oded True, but why waste a mods time? I'd imagine it'd be pretty simple?

Comment: For the occasional error that doesn't result in any lasting effects, though wasting a few moderator cycles, my thinking that the effort required for this is too high.

Comment: @Oded don't forget the flag weight: for new users, having the first flag declined cause major drop in the weight causing their future flags to be ignored or handled slower.